# Using dictionary to modify list values

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

I need to change all "a" to " AM" and "p" to " PM" from list1.

```
dict1 = {
    "a": " AM",
    "p": " PM"
}

list1 = ["1:34a", "2:34p", "4:12a"]

def ampm(value):
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        return value.replace(k,v)
    
for item in list1:
    print (ampm(item))
```

I have no idea why it results in:

> 1:34 AM
>
> 2:34p
>
> 4:12 AM

Comment: You return from your first loop iteration, thus never reach key `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return from the first iteration. You could improve it like so

```
def ampm(value):
    for k,v in dict1.items():
        value = value.replace(k,v)
    return value
```